# Reset class when "unhovering" item

Tags: javascript, rating-system

I got my first star-rating up and running, however, I am missing a single-part.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="rating">
  <a class="star-link" href="/vote?hack=3&amp;rating=1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty star inline star-active" data-hack="3" data-rating="1" id="3-star-1"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="star-link" href="/vote?hack=3&amp;rating=2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty star inline star-active" data-hack="3" data-rating="2" id="3-star-2"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="star-link" href="/vote?hack=3&amp;rating=3">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty star inline star-active" data-hack="3" data-rating="3" id="3-star-3"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="star-link" href="/vote?hack=3&amp;rating=4">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty star inline star-active" data-hack="3" data-rating="4" id="3-star-4"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="star-link" href="/vote?hack=3&amp;rating=5">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty star inline" data-hack="3" data-rating="5" id="3-star-5"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
javascript:
  $('span.star').hover(function() {
    hack_id = this.dataset.hack;
    rating = this.dataset.rating;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= rating) {
        $('#' + hack_id + '-star-' + i).addClass('star-active');
      } else {
        $('#' + hack_id + '-star-' + i).removeClass('star-active');
      }
    }
  });
```

Now, when I hover over the star(s) it applies the class just fine and also removes the class of those stars that are not needed.
My last problem though is that once the class(es) were applied and I move my mouse somewhere else, it does not undo the changes.
I pretty much need some kind of:

```
if (not hovering over any star)
   remove all classes set before
endif
```

I know this is a very basic task but I can not seem to get through it.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of the CSS pseudo-class `hover` ?

Comment: `hover` takes 2 handlers, it is merely a shortcut for `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`   You can apply the removal of the classes in the handlerOut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery's mouseout(): http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

also, instead of using jquery to apply classes you can simply define in your css

```
.star-active:hover{
/*whatever you have in .start-active now*/
}
```

then you won't need any jquery/js for this

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work I think as I want ALL the stars to the left of the one I am hovering over to get the hover-effect.

Comment: Anyways, this was exactly what I was looking for :)
I will probably work on it in version 2, but for today it's enough to use some 'bad'ly coded JS ;)

Thank you all very much!